# Surface Area with Two Cylinders

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Find the surface area of the solid obtained by intersecting
the solid cylinder y$^2$+z$^2$ ≤ 4 with the solid cylinder x
$^2$+z
$^2$ ≤ 4.

So, I calculated it via symmetry: You can multiply the surface area of x$^2$ + z$^2$ = 4 by the area lying over disk y$^z$ + z$^2$ ≤ 4 by 8. How did you guys/would you guys do it?

Comment: You can see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid#Surface_area